# How to write a dictionary report into a file

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

Given a report (which is just a dictionary) and a filename, I want to be able to write into the supplied file name all of the contents of the report. I want to make sure I don't overwrite anything in the filename. This is what I have:

```
def write_report(r, filename):
input_filename=open(filename, "a")
new_report= input_filename.append(r)
filename.close()
return new_report
```

But I get this error when I test it:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

How do I append something into a file?

Comment: Replace `append` with `write`.

Comment: + You may also want to write a newline (`\n`).

Comment: _" I want to be able to write into the supplied file **name** all of the contents of the report"_ Really ? Into the file **NAME** ?! Are uou **SURE** ??!!

Comment: doesn't that overwrite anything that's in the file already? If I use write?

Comment: I don't obtain the error message you said but this one: ``AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'append'``. Are you sure to be rigorous ?

Comment: Performs your own essays. Isn't it a fantastic idea ? That's what SO is for : giving great ideas on such complex problems as yours !

Comment: @eyquem well give me a great idea about my complex problem

Comment: I was kind of sarcastic, you know... But really: do as I did, perform tests on a file whose content you don't care of, and see what are the results with the modes ``'r'``, ``'r+'``, ``'a'``, ``'a+'`` and if you don't understand the results, THEn you'll ask questions. But internet is full of pages treating this question. Is it really necessary to add a 5.001.204th one ? Moreover, you can search on stackoverflow.com, the answers that already exist to this kind of problem: see at the right angle, up.

Comment: Note that it isn't the function ``write()`` that decides of the writing mode, it is the mode argument passed at the moment the file is opened. The modes are 'w', 'w+', 'r', 'r+', 'a', 'a+' and also 'rb', 'rb+', etc for opening in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to write dictionary to a file;

```
>>> import json
>>> d = dict.fromkeys('abcde')
#Write
with open('abc.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
#Read
with open('abc.json') as f:
    print (json.load(f))
...     
{'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None, 'e': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two errors there.

1. The method to write to a file is `write()`, not `append()`
2. You're calling `close()` on a `string`, you should `close()` the file object `input_filename`.

Also, you may want to rename `input_filename` to `output_file`.

Comment: Wouldln't write() overwrite anything that already exists in the file?

Comment: No, because the file was opened in append mode (`"a"`)